Remove specific indices in each row of a numpy ndarray
I have integer arrays of the type:
import numpy as np

seed_idx = np.asarray([[0, 1],
                       [1, 2],
                       [2, 3],
                       [3, 4]], dtype=np.int_)

target_idx = np.asarray([[2,9,4,1,8],
                         [9,7,6,2,4],
                         [1,0,0,4,9],
                         [7,1,2,3,8]], dtype=np.int_)


For each row of target_idx, I want to select the elements whose indices are not the ones in seed_idx. The resulting array should thus be:
[[4,1,8],
 [9,2,4],
 [1,0,9],
 [7,1,2]]

In other words, I want to do something similar to np.take_along_axis(target_idx, seed_idx, axis=1), but excluding the indices instead of keeping them.
What is the most elegant way to do this? I find it surprisingly annoying to find something neat.

You can mask out the values you don't want with np.put_along_axis and then index the others:
>>> np.put_along_axis(target_idx, seed_idx, -1, axis=1)
>>> target_idx[np.where(target_idx != -1)].reshape(len(target_idx), -1)
array([[4, 1, 8],
       [9, 2, 4],
       [1, 0, 9],
       [7, 1, 2]])

If -1 is a valid value, use target_idx.min() - 1.

That's the solution I had come to as well, but it still feels quite clumsy. I'll wait to see if there are a few more suggestions and if not I'll accept this one. Thanks for the tip for the valid value.

@Ben Is your seed_idx always going to be this predictable shape (it's like a parallelogram)? If so, some stride tricks might be possible.

In general, seed_idx will always have shape (..., M) and target_idx will always have shape (..., N), where N > M and where the (...,) are the same batch shape in both cases.

I don't mean the array dimensions, I mean that rhomboid/staircase geometrical shape of the masked out values ("shape" was a confusing word to use in hindsight).

Ah no, that was just for example's sake, sorry!

I thought about using put_along_axis on a mask, but I settled on raveling and deleting with linear indexing.
m, n = seed_idx.shape
i = seed_idx + np.arange(m)[:, np.newaxis]*n  # calculate linear indices
out = np.delete(target_idx.ravel(), i)  # remove them
out = out.reshape(m, -1)  # reshape


That's a nice one. You could show the intermediate i to demonstrate the logic ;)
